# Element goes to the end of the list

Tags: java, list

So, guys. I'm really new to Java (and any other programming language for that matter) and I've been experiencing some trouble dealing with lists. I've written this piece of code as to integrate a function, given the inferior and superior limits, and the pacing. Although, I've notice that for a pacing different from 1, the list (list_x) gets messed up and a value goes right to the end of it.
Here follows the complete code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Integrate {
    static List<Double> fillx(double ini,double end, double pace) { //Fills the x column
        List<Double> list_x = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(double i = ini; i <= (end+0.1*pace); i += pace) {
           int i2 = (int) ((i-ini)/pace);
           list_x.add(i2, i);
        }
        System.out.println(list_x);
        return list_x;
    }
    static List<List<Double>> filly(List<Double> listx){ //Fills the y column
        List<List<Double>> listxy= new ArrayList<List<Double>>();
        for(int i = 0; i < listx.size();i++) {
            List<Double> pair = new ArrayList<Double>();
            pair.add(0,listx.get(i));
            pair.add(1,function(listx.get(i)));
            listxy.add(i,pair);
            System.out.println(pair);
        }
        return listxy;
    }
    static double function(double x) { //Defines the function to be integrated
    return x;
    }
    static double integrate(List<List<Double>> listxy) { //Integrates following trapezoidal forms
        double area = 0;
        for(int i=0; (i+1) < listxy.size();i++) {
           area += 0.5*(listxy.get(i+1).get(0)-listxy.get(i).get(0))*      (listxy.get(i+1).get(1)+listxy.get(i).get(1));
           System.out.println(listxy.get(i+1).get(0)+" "+listxy.get(i).get(0)+" "+listxy.get(i+1).get(1)+" "+listxy.get(i).get(1));
        }
        return area;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        double ini = scan.nextDouble(); //Reads the inferior limit
        double end = scan.nextDouble(); //Reads the superior limit
        double pace = scan.nextDouble(); //Reads the pace (partial to be summed).
        if (((end-ini) % pace) < pace) {
        System.out.println(integrate(filly(fillx(ini,end,pace))));}
        else
            System.out.println("Must review pace");
   }
}
```

And I get these results (with values of ini = 0, end = 1, pace =1E-1

```
[0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.30000000000000004, 0.4, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7999999999999999, 0.8999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999, 0.5]
```

I'd be really glad if you had any other remarks as well. Since I'm learning by myself, all help is welcome.

Comment: You're adding a lot of stuff with a specific index. I hope you know that, this will shift elements with a larger index one "place" to the right. [JavaDoc List#add(int, E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29).

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is always true: `if (((end-ini) % pace) < pace) `

Comment: @Bohemian: Let `end = -3, ini = 0, pace = -2`.  Then `((end-ini) % pace) == -1`, which is greater than -2.  Not sure if that's relevant to this question, and it is a suspicious expression, but it's good to remember that `%` isn't mathematical modulus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you construct the list_x, this is what happens:

```
adding 0.0 at index 0    [0.0]
...
adding 0.5 at index 5    [0,0, 0.1,... 0.5]
adding 0.6 at index 5     Bang: [0,0, 0.1,... 0.6, 0.5]
adding 0.7 at index 6    [0,0, 0.1,... 0.6, 0.7, 0.5]
```

You see how this pushes 0.5 to the end.

You are doing what is known as "overengineering": afraid not doing enough, you do too much.

```
// The List is perfectly capable of appending at the end, which is exactly what you want:
for(double i = ini; i <= (end+0.1*pace); i += pace) {
    list_x.add(i);
}
```

Much more needs to be said. I'll add a few remarks - hang on.

**Footnote 1** Double arithmetic

```
int i2 = (int) ((i-ini)/pace);
```

Such computations are risky. The division may result in a value at or slightly above an integer and then the cast to int truncates and yields what you expect. It may, however, return a double slightly below (see those 0.x999999999999999) and then truncation results in one less as you expect.

```
int i2 = (int)Math.round((i-ini)/pace);
```

**Footnote 2** Compute a series of doubles

Instead of adding a double repeatedly to another double, calculate it directly. (I've also added ini, to get the correct abscissa values.)

```
int n = (int)Math.round((end - ini)/pace) + 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    list_x.add(ini + i*pace);
}
```

**Footnode 3** Use an adequate class

A list of two isn't a good way for storing a pair of coordinates. A simple class Point can be defined:

```
public class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;
    Point( double x, double y ){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getX(){
        return x;
    }
    public double getY(){
        return y;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return "<" + x + "," + y + ">";
    }
}
```

Now, the x-y-combinations can be computed like this:

```
static List<Point> fillp(List<Double> listx){
    List<Point> listp = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < listx.size(); i++) {
    Point p = new Point( listx.get(i), function(listx.get(i)) );
        listp.add( p );
    }
    return listp;
}
```

**Footnote 4** Why all these Lists?

There's no need to store values that can be computed easily or are only computed once anyway. Simply compute them on the fly. This simplifies your code:

```
public class Trapez {
    static double function(double x) { //Defines the function to be integrated
        return x;
    }

    static double trapezoidalRule( double a, double b, double h ){
        int n = (int)Math.round((b - a)/h) + 1;
        double area = 0;
        double y = function( a );
        for( int i = 1; i < n; i++ ){
            double y1 = function( a + h*i );
            area += 0.5*h*(y + y1);
            y = y1;
        }
        return area;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( trapezoidalRule( 0, 1, 0.1 ) );
    }
}
```

**Conclusion** A better way for passing the function?

Java 8 has functional forms (lambdas). In simple cases they are easy to use, and I conclude my discussion with the removal of method `function`. (I've used f(x) = 2x to make the function definition distinctive from the argument.)

```
import java.util.function.Function;
public class Trapez {
    static double trapezoidalRule( Function<Double,Double> f, double a, double b, double h ){
        int n = (int)Math.round((b - a)/h) + 1;
        double area = 0;
        double y = f.apply( a );
        for( int i = 1; i < n; i++ ){
            double y1 = f.apply( a + h*i );
            area += 0.5*h*(y + y1);
            y = y1;
        }
        return area;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println( trapezoidalRule( x -> 2*x, 0, 1, 0.1 ) );
    }
}
```